# ssl certificate for www.mywebsite.com works but not for mywebsite.com

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate

I bought certificate for my website. Our sysadmin installed it and it works correctly but for domain with `www` but if I type without `www` the browser show me certificate error. Don't suppose that I should by 2 certificates for this purpose and assume that is configuration issue, am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways for protecting both the domains with a single SSL certificate and they are:-

**Purchasing an SSL certificate from those brands who gives such facility**:
SSL Brands like RapidSSL and GeoTrust provide the advance feature of securing the WWW domain name and non-WWW domain name by single certificate. Within such process when the certificate is issued, generate the CSR (code signing request) key for the www domain and in turn it will secure a non www domain. For example, if the CSR is generated for www.mydomain.com then it will also work in hand for mydomain.com. The browser will show the “http” before the both addresses.

**Redirecting the non www domain to the www domain**:
If you have already purchased an SSL certificate from other brand, then this alternative way is free of cost as it can be achieved at development level. For this you need to use “301″ redirection. “301″ is the HTTP response status code for redirecting permanently to another URL location. Suppose you type abc.com then it should be redirected to www.abc.com. You can then acquire an SSL certificate for WWW domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Installing wildcard SSL certificate**:
Wildcard SSL certificate provides security to unlimited sub domains if purchased for a single domain. If you purchase a wildcard certificate for yourdomain.com, your www.yourdomain.com will be secured along with every other sub domains of your site.

The redirection option is not that convenient because it requires a thorough change in the coding of the website. Whereas purchasing the wildcard certificate is the costliest choice.

Comment: Redirection only solves half the problem, since https:// abc.com would not redirect without certificate error.

Comment: exactly. I need redirect to https://www. and when I did that I got browser certificate error

Comment: Clearly, you want visitors to be able to use an SSL connection whether they visit example.com or www.example.com. To enable this functionality, you can use Apache rewrite rules in a custom .htaccess file.
    
I've added lines from apache config todemonstrate how to redirect visitors who enter a domain name without the www prefix to a secure connection. With these settings enabled on your web site, visitors who go to example.com or www.example.com (where abc.com represents your domain) both obtain an SSL connection

Comment: @malyy yes we have exactly lines in our htaccess. But on redirect I see browser certificate error like are you sure... add exception etc..

Comment: to be on the same page, please provide me with a link

Comment: @malyy: if `abc.com` is not in the certificate's list of valid names, you cannot get anything https from there without a certificate warning, not even  a redirect to www.abc.com.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz: in general yes, but it's quit a good thing to view certificate by myself in order to prove one thing or propose another one (e.g ubject Alternative Names , etc)